# Can I inject a annotation into a pojo

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, introspection

Lets say I have a POJO that looks like this.

```
public class SomeDataClass {

    @SomeProperty1
    String myField1;

    @SomeProperty1
    String myField2;

    ...

    getters()... 
    setters()... // you know the drill

}
```

I want to be able to synthetically inject an annotation to an instantiated object. The new POJO, if I were to inspect it using reflection, would actually look like this:

```
public class SomeDataClass {

    @SomeProperty1
    String myField1;

    @SomeProperty1
--> @SomeProperty2 <--- the logic flow would change depending on whether this annotation is present
    String myField2;

    ...

    getters()... 
    setters()... // you know the drill

}
```

Is this possible? How could I accomplish something like this?

Comment: Through reflection you do not inspect instances, you inspect classes (which are instances themselves, but you know what I mean).

Comment: Annotations are part of the invariant class structure. They are unrelated to instantiated objects and therefore, can’t get injected into instantiated objects. …and they are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

[Annotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation) are just syntactic metadata providers...

so you should get by reflection the name of the declared fields in the given class and use the desired criteria to discriminate **which one of those fields** needs the info that `@SomeProperty2` is providing, after that adding the info from `@SomeProperty2` at run time is just a normal use of setter or getters...

Comment: The problem is that I have a class of 2000 field definitions.  This is a class to represent data fields in a cobol program.